# Linq one to many relations as comma separated values

Tags: entity-framework, linq, join

I have a product table with one to many relationship to another 2 tables.

**Product**:

1. ProductId
2. ProductName
3. IsDeleted (bit)

**ProductTag**:

1. ProductTagId
2. ProductId
3. TagName
4. IsDeleted (bit)

**ProductCategory**:

1. ProductCategoryId
2. ProductId
3. CategoryName
4. IsDeleted (bit)

I need a result like the following in a single linq query and while using join I need to check the IsDeleted flag too. Please help.

Required output:

```
1 | Adidas_Shoes | shoes,new,adidas,sport | Mens,Shoes,Adidas
```

---

Just tried to join 1 table as follows

> (from p in Product join pt in ProductTag on p.ProductId equals
>   pt.ProductId into productTags from pt in productTags.DefaultIfEmpty()
>   where (pt==null || !pt.IsDeleted) select new { ProductId =
>   p.ProductId, ProductName = p.ProductName, Tags = string.Join(",",
>   pt.TagName.ToArray()) }).Distinct().ToList()

Comment: Just tried to join 1 table as follows
(from p in Product
join pt in ProductTag on p.ProductId equals pt.ProductId
into productTags
from pt in productTags.DefaultIfEmpty()
where (pt==null || !pt.IsDeleted)
select new {
ProductId = p.ProductId,
ProductName = p.ProductName,
Tags = string.Join(",", pt.TagName.ToArray())
}).Distinct().ToList();

Comment: You should improved your question.

Comment: In the select query for product, I need values as Tags="shoes,new,adidas,sport", Categories="Mens,Shoes,Adidas"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you should have posted some code that you have tried with, maybe a slimmed down version of your DbContext, but in the end you need to iterate over your products and left join on tag and category names

```
var query = from product in context.Products
            let tags = from tag in context.Tags
                        where !tag.IsDeleted
                            && tag.ProductId == product.ProductId
                        select tag.TagName
            let categories = from category in context.Categories
                        where !category.IsDeleted
                         && category.ProductId == product.ProductId
                        select category.CategoryName
            where !product.IsDeleted
            select new
            {
                Id = product.ProductId,
                Name = product.ProductName,
                Tags = string.Join(", ", tags)
                Categories = string.Join(" ", categories)
            };
```

Note: Due to the lack of any mappings information i simply assume that you don't have navigational properties defined, but feel free to adapt the above to match your particular setup

Note: in case you find yourself always excluding deleted entities from your query you should start considering tackling [EF soft delete](https://www.google.be/search?q=EF%20soft%20delete%20site%3Astackoverflow.com&oq=EF%20soft%20delete%20site%3Astackoverflow.com) scenarios, and among those one is to deal with discriminators

```
  modelBuilder.Entity<Foo>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));
  modelBuilder.Entity<Bar>().Map(m => m.Requires("IsDeleted").HasValue(false));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.. 
Sorry for adding only few specifications.