# Comma separated Names with multiple columns as group by using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, linq

I have a list which has following result set .

```
 public class PrExport
    {
        public string pId { get; set; }
        public string prName { get; set; }
        public string hId { get; set; }
        public string hName { get; set; }
        public string np { get; set; }
        public string ftId { get; set; }
        public string paName { get; set; }
    }

List<PrExport> prTable = new List<PrExport>();
```

```
prTable =some 3rdparty service returns the result set as below;
```

[image]

I want the result set set as below
[image]

This is the code I have used.

```
var res = from c in prTable 
group c by new { c.pId, c.prName, c.hId, c.hName, c.np, c.ftId } into gr
                      select new PrExport()
                      {
                          pId = gr.Key?.pId,
                          prName = gr.Key?.prName,
                          hId = gr.Key?.hId,
                          hName = gr.Key?.hName,
                          np = gr.Key?.np,
                          ftId = gr.Key?.ftId,
                          paName = string.Join(",", gr.Select(c => c?.paName))
                      };
            return prTable = res.ToList();
```

I'm getting the result set as below .Here I'm not getting comma seperated paName which I wanted.What am I missing here?

[image]

Comment: I do not see mistakes, except same alias usage, try to change this part `string.Join(",", gr.Select(x => x?.paName))`

Comment: Thanks @SvyatoslavDanyliv ! I have changed and tried the following way .but it's throwing error .  paName = string.Join(",", gr.Select(c => c.paName.ToString()).ToArray())

Comment: `np` != `npi` - your code works fine if I change everything to `npi` - https://dotnetfiddle.net/4BrByw

Comment: Similarly to @RandRandom, I took your code and tried it - it works fine other than the `npi` / `np` typo - https://dotnetfiddle.net/klgBMo. If you're still having problems can you include a [mcve]

Comment: @CharlesMager - so many line breaks my eyes hurt :)

Comment: @RandRandom - That was a typo.In my actual it was np only .Which means I already have the only np in the code . But still not working .Let me run again

Comment: For the time-being I flaged to close the question, since everything works as described, and you have an unknown issue.

Comment: Use the debugger and look at the data in res just before you return. Perhaps the grouping is fine, the data is truly there and you simply  have a display issue

Answer (score 0):

As others have pointed out your code seems to be fine.

I don’t know how you produced the pictures of the tables but if that is a CSV file opened in e.g. Excel, it will not allow a comma `,` inside one of the values unless you use semi colon `;` as delimiter in your CSV file.

Answer (score 0):

check this out it may help you.

```
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48723477/linq-one-to-many-relations-as-comma-separated-values
```